# Get params of jQuery AJAX request on complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I find out what parameters were passed to an (asynchronous) jQuery AJAX request after it is complete?

Basically, I am firing a bunch of AJAX requests with different id passed as a parameter and displaying the results to the user when each of them finishes. Now, if the request is successful, I can pass the id back in the result of the request. But, if the request fails, I don't know which request failed, i.e. for what id was that request.

Example (javascript/jQuery):

```
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get-results.php", 
        data: { 'id': i },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xmlReq) {

            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#result" + data.id).html(data.result);

        },
        error: function(xmlReq, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var id= ???;
            $("#result" + id).html('error bla bla');

        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the current value of `i` for the `error` function. And you capture with a closure. So:

```
error: function(id) {
    return function(xmlReq, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $("#result" + id).html('error bla bla');

    };
}(i)
```

That is `error` is the result of immediately calling an anonymous function passing in the current value of `i`.

Comment: Exactly! So it is actually needed to 'instantiate' the function with the current value to create a closure. Thanks! Too bad I can't mark both yours and Rocket's answers as accepted.

Comment: Rocket's was more specific to jQuery (and therefore better for your question), mine was more generic (and may help elsewhere in the future).

Comment: Actually now, upon further testing, I think this is a better solution, since this way of passing vars can be used even if the request succeeds, but returns malformed data (from which the id cannot be extracted).

Answer (score 3):

[`$.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) gives you the data send via the AJAX call.

`.ajaxError(handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError))`

The `ajaxOptions` object contains all the options that can be set via [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

So, instead of using the `error:` option in `$.ajax`, use `$.ajaxError`.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  if(ajaxOptions.url.indexOf('get-results.php') != -1){
    var data = ajaxOptions.data; // this is a string: 'id=1&param2=4'
                                 // to get the ID, you need to parse this
  }
});
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Although, for some reason, ajaxOptions.data is actually a string in my case ('id=0', 'id=1' etc.), but that's not an issue. Wonder why I can't access the ajaxOptions object from the 'error' handler in the $.ajax() call.

Comment: @Dejan, I looked at the jQuery API, and `ajaxOptions.data` should always be a string, let me fix that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that Javascript supports closures, and just write the variable name (but be careful to copy it inside the `for` block scope so that it does not change):

```
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var INDEX = i;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get-results.php", 
        data: { 'id': i },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xmlReq) {

            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#result" + data.id).html(data.result);

        },
        error: function(xmlReq, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            var id = INDEX;
            $("#result" + id).html('error bla bla');

        }
   });
}
```

I believe that this is what you want.

Comment: That doesn't work. In your example, INDEX gets overwritten in each iteration of the loop.  So, in each call of the error handler, the value of INDEX will be 9 (the value which was assigned to it in the last iteration).

Comment: @Dejan: Works for me. The closure means it should work. Although the name `INDEX` is reused for the loop's scope in the next iteration, the _actual object_ that had that name in the previous iteration still exists, used in the closure for the function.

Comment: @Dejan: For a really simple example, run the following which is essentially the same thing with the jQuery abstracted out. You'll see that it alerts 0-9 in succession. (Sorry about having to bunch it on one line!) `var funcs = []; for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { var INDEX = i; funcs[funcs.length-1] = function() { alert(INDEX); }(); } for each (var i in funcs) { funcs[i](); }`

Comment: Try this:
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    var INDEX = i;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "any-url-that-doesnt-exist.php", 
        data: { 'id': i },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xmlReq) {
        },
        error: function(xmlReq, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var id = INDEX;
            alert(id);
        }
   });
}

Pops '9' each time. Maybe I forgot to mention that the requests are asynchronous?

Comment: @Dejan: I copied your code verbatim, and for me works perfectly. Firefox 3.6.13 and IE 8.0.7600, jQuery 1.2.6 and 1.4.2. Don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: I get all 9s too. Chrome and jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: What about Firefox or IE? Is it just me, or is this a browser issue?

Comment: Just tested in Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera, all 9s. In IE there are no popups at all (maybe because of some security settings in IE?). jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: @Dejan: I can't explain that at all. It works for me, and both logic and the relevant standards say that it should behave properly. This is a key feature of closures in Javascript. Anyway, I'm glad you got another solution.

Comment: I'm not really sure that there is a closure here (@boyetboy posted an example how to make it a closure). Though it is weird that it works on your machine and not on mine. But, thanks for the effort anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass them back with your response.

Comment: My question was how I can get them if the request fails, i.e. there is no response.

Comment: I guess you'll need to set up some sort of request queue/stack/array and manage the status of each entry as the responses come back.

Comment: So there is no way to extract them from the XMLHttpRequest object (which I get passed to the error hadler)?

Comment: @Dejan: Store them in some appropriate place in your code. We cannot know where that is.

Comment: I already have the ids in an array (or they are 0-9 like in the example, it doesn't matter). But, again, the question is how can I know WHICH request failed?